# string handling in bash

Tags: bash

the problem I met is like this:
given a string `dimensioning-inspection_depth-0rules_20120306-084158`
I'd like to get the first part of the string: `dimensioning-inspection_depth-0rules`, so to speak, get rid of the time stamp part. In perl, it's like a piece of work to do the job using regular expression. But since I'm new to  bash, I'd like to know
the best-practice way of doing it in Bash.

Comment: How do you tell the first part from the second part?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to pipe the string to sed, you can use Bash variable mangling:

```
$ string=dimensioning-inspection_depth-0rules_20120306-084158
$ echo ${string%_*}
dimensioning-inspection_depth-0rules
```

More information on variable mangling [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
str=dimensioning-inspection_depth-0rules_20120306-084158
echo ${str%_*}
```

This will remove anything after and including the last `_` in the string, so if your string always has the form `something_date-time`, you will always be left with `something` part.

More info here:

- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 2):

```
a="dimensioning-inspection_depth-0rules_20120306-084158"
echo $a | head -c -16
```

So as the timestamp will always be equal width (16 characters that you are trying to trim off the end in this case), `head -c -16` should work for you